# Unable to edit specific values of controls while debugging

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, debugging, edit

got a little problem:

I've got a control and I want to enable, for example, the autosize or set the dock to fill. But whenever I try to do this and press Enter, it just changes immediatly back to the value before.

And yes, Edit while Debugging is enabled.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean to say you're trying to change desige time properties of your user control whilst the app is running in debug mode ?

Comment: Yes, to be more specific: Winform Controls.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that - you need to stop debugging, do your changes and then recompile and run. Design time properties can't be altered at run time

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for that information :) If you want a "correct answer" just answer it right know, i will vote.

Comment: @auburg: I never came across a property that I could not change at runtime. Can you provide a normative reference?

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve], please? I can't reproduce

Comment: @ThomasWeller You _can_ change properties like autosize / dock size programatically at run time but the OP is asking about changing those values in the designer at run time which you can't do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to properties in the designer aren't allowed whilst the program is running